# Transparency of image in a grid

Tags: html, css, extjs

I've a little problem with my extjs 4.2 MVC app with grid and image transparency:
this is my grid:

```
Ext.define('XProject.view.message.inbox.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.inboxgrid',
    store: 'message.Inbox',
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'  ,
        'XMailweb.view.message.inbox.CtxMenu'
    ],

    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
            if ((record.get('Flags') & 2 )== 0) {
                return "boldFont";
            }
            if (record.get('Err_Id') != 0) {
                return "redFont";
            }            
        }
    },

    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    selModel: {
        checkOnly: false,
        injectCheckbox: 0
    },    

    features : [{
        ftype: 'filters',
        autoReload: false, 
        encode:true,
        paramPrefix : 'Filter'
    }],

    columns: [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        cls: 'attach',
        width: 18,
        dataIndex: 'Files_Num',
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable:false,
        text: 'Attachment',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record ){
            if (value >= 1){
                metaData.css  = 'attach';
            }
            return '';
        }       
    }]
})
```

other columns are omitted.
My css role is :

```
.attach {
    background:transparent url('../icons/attach.png') no-repeat center left !important;
    text-indent: -250px;
}
```

my attach.png is transparent, but when grid is rendered (with alternate row background color) appear with white background.
This is my transparent image:
[image: Attach.png]

And my rendered grid:

[image]

Why does not have transparent background (all css images in grid)?
I try with firefox and iexplorer, but result it's the same.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:transparent** overide the background color.

Use :

```
.attach,.attach .x-column-header-over{
    background-image:url('../icons/attach.png') !important;
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
}
```

Between :

```
background:transparent url('../icons/attach.png') no-repeat center left !important;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/521/

Comment: You're great! Another problem is in the header of attach: when on mouseover, icon hide. why?

Comment: You need to overide the .x-column-header-over background

Comment: If i have other header with others images? how can i do?

Comment: You create a new column and new class.

Comment: Now is perfect [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/davymartu/Xpe9V/524/) thank you so much